# Microsoft VPC or VirtualBox for virtual Ubuntu install in Windows 7

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, microsoft-virtual-pc

I am planning on installing 32-bit Ubuntu inside a virtual machine on a Windows machine (Dell Latitude E6500). I have plenty of memory, and sufficient hard drive space to manage this, but I'm wondering if there's any particular reason to prefer VirtualBox over Microsoft's Virtual PC for this usage.

Anyone have any solid, objective reasons to prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answers to this question: 
[Can you install Ubuntu Server in a Windows PC VM on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/23248/can-you-install-ubuntu-server-in-a-windows-pc-vm-on-windows-7)

Short version of highest rated answer at the time: MS VPC was designed to run Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the specific Linux support (against MS's specific Linux non-support) Virtual Box also gives you a lot of other features - USB, hardware accelrated video, and a lot more disk snapshot options.

Answer (score 1):

I have personally experienced lots of crashing with Microsoft's product. VirtualBox is much more stable, free, cross platform, more features, etc... :)